# How to store customer data in mysql (2 tables vs 1 table)

Tags: mysql

I was thinking that I would have two tables for mysql. One for storing login information and the other for shipping address.  Is that the conventional way or is everything store in one table?

For two tables... is there a way where it automatically copies a column from table A to table B, so that I can reference the same id to grab their shipping address...

Comment: Can a customer have single shipping address or can he have multiple shipping addresses ?

Comment: single address for now. everytime he checks out, he can update it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If its a single address and if it is going to be updated everytime , then you can have it in a single table something like

```
**Customer** 

customer_id [pkey]
customer_name
login_id
password
shipping_address
```

whereas if you want to store all the shipping addresses for a single customer(across multiple visits) then it would be a good design to have another table customer_shipping_address

```
**Customer**

customer_id [pkey]
customer_name
login_id
password

**Customer_Shipping_Address**

customer_id [fkey to customer]
shipping_address
```

Comment: Having an extra flag in customer_shipping_address to identify which is the default shipping address will also be a good feature to have

Answer (score 0):

This is my answer to your question regarding using 1 table or 2 tables. This decision depends on may factors. But i would suggest that you should use 2 separate tables. Because the log-in information is something that you will be retrieving very often compare to shipping information. Now if you have all the info in one table then table size will be huge and you will have to query this huge table everytime you need login information of user.

Answer (score 0):

I think using two tables is better way to go. then just join them when you want to do the shipping.
The SQL for that would be like this.

```
SELECT
table1.id, table2.id, table2.somethingelse, table1.somethingels
FROM
table1 INNER JOIN table2
ON table1.foreignkey = table2.primarykey
WHERE
    (some conditions is true)
```

The code above would need to be run on the shiping page itself.